# Iterate in array of type struct

Tags: arrays, for-loop, go, struct, types

I'm quite new on Go and my goal is to access to single properties in an slice array of struct.

Code (file api.go):

```
package api

type DirStruct struct {
    dirName      string
    dirPath      string
    foldersCount int
    filesCount   int
}
/*this function works*/
func ListPathContent(path string) ([]*DirStruct, error) {
    results := []*DirStruct{}

    files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(path)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)

        return results, errors.New("Error -> get path " + path)
    }

    for _, f := range files {

        if f.IsDir() {

            dirPath := path + "\\" + f.Name()
            filesCount := 0
            foldersCount := 0
            dircontent, _ := ioutil.ReadDir(dirPath)

            for _, d := range dircontent {
                if d.IsDir() {
                    foldersCount++
                } else {
                    filesCount++
                }

            }

            el := new(DirStruct)
            el.dirName = f.Name()
            el.dirPath = dirPath
            el.foldersCount = foldersCount
            el.filesCount = filesCount

            results = append(results, el)
        }
    }

    return results, nil
```

Code (main.go)

```
import //.... other pkg
import "./api"


func main() {

    
    ListPathContent, _ := api.ListPathContent("C:")

    


    
    for _, p := range ListPathContent {
        /* <--------- HERE'S the problem ---------> */
        /* I can't do the the simplest and most obvious thing like this
        fmt.Println(p.dirName) or fmt.Println(p.dirPath)

        then the error is "p.dirName undefined (cannot refer to unexported field or method dirName)"

        


         */





    }


}
```

Surely the answer is there under my eyes, but it is impossible for me to access the properties and if I do `fmt.Println(p)` it returns all the struct in JSON-like format `&{$WINDOWS.~BT C:\$WINDOWS.~BT 1 0}`  so the data is in there, but it is inaccessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All identifiers defined in a package are private to that package if its name starts with a lowercase letter. This is called *unexported*. This rule applies to struct fields as well.

You must export identifiers if you want to refer to them from other packages. So simply start their names with an uppercased letter:

```
type DirStruct struct {
    DirName      string
    DirPath      string
    FoldersCount int
    FilesCount   int
}
```

[Spec: Exported identifiers:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers)

> An identifier may be *exported* to permit access to it from another package. An identifier is exported if both:
>
> 1. the first character of the identifier's name is a Unicode upper case letter (Unicode class "Lu"); and
> 2. the identifier is declared in the [package block](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blocks) or it is a [field name](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) or [method name](https://golang.org/ref/spec#MethodName).
>
> All other identifiers are not exported.

If you're new to the language, please take the [Go Tour](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1) first. This is covered in the [Basics: Exported names](https://tour.golang.org/basics/3).

Comment: First of all, thank you so much. I knew I had the solution under my eyes. In fact, for all public declarations (functions, structs), I had always written the first capital letter. But I would not have imagined that the same would be the same for the properties. In my mind, subconsciously, the properties of the struct became public as the parent object was.

This is a new world for me and yes, I must pay more attention to docs.